Math mode: centering/aligning the entire fraction height, vertically, in a series sum with the operation signs exactly centered, as well
I'm interested in learning something more about LaTex syntax and semantics. So this isn't a question about best-practices when writing math-mode expressions. That's a different discussion I'd prefer to avoid. I'd just like to know how to achieve an effect discussed below.
Just to be clear, the following is only an example to help better illustrate the question. It's not an example of a real problem. So please take it as a syntax question about achieving a specific semantic behavior, using this example only for illustration purposes, and not a question about this example should look to a mathematics reader.
In writing a fraction today, I achieved the following:

Just using the usual \frac notation and adding \large for the green-circled 1 values above, per the following coding:
\frac{1}{1+{\frac{\large 1}{C_{2(s)}}\,\cdot\,P_{2(s)}}+\frac{\large 1+\frac1{C_{2(s)}\,\cdot\,P_{2(s)}}-\frac1{P_{2(s)}}}{C_{1(s‌​)}\,\cdot\,P_{1(s)}}‌​}

Normally, I'm more focused on communicating and less worried about finer details of formatting. But this time, perhaps in part because the fine details of this particular formatting actually drew more of my attention this time, I wondered how I might have managed to vertically center all of the fractions/terms so that it looked like this, instead:

And I realized that I'm ignorant about how I might approach that goal, were I to want it.
(Note that I just moved things around in Paint and that I only adjusted three terms in the denominator to illustrate my goal. I didn't adjust the numerator of the 3rd term.)
I'd like to know how to find the total height of the tallest fraction in a sum like this, such as the last one in the denominator here, and then find the height of each of the shorter fractions and center each of them vertically within the height of the tallest one, as shown above.
The + operations should all line up with each other, as well, while also being centered vertically.
If this isn't difficult to achieve, that would teach me something that may yet help me someday. I'd appreciate adding that to my mental toolset. If it is difficult to achieve, then explaining why it is so difficult would also be a fine answer. Either way, I'd appreciate the education.

Please always include a full test document, it is hard to know what code you are using or how to modify it to achieve what you ask, especially as you hint that you are using \large which is invalid in math mode and generates warnings saying it should not be used.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. I will take a moment and include what I used in the first case.
